# Automatic interpolated strings

Tags: c#, .net, roslyn, toolchain

I have used interpolated strings (ie  $"Hello my name is {name}" ) for a while and I use this much more heavily than ordinary strings.

Is there a way to tell the compiler that to always assume that a string is interpolated so I don't have to type the dollar sign?

Using event variable, a #pragma, something in .sln, or a nuget package?

Comment: No. There's nothing like that available in the language.

Comment: I would love a Visual Studio feature that fills in a $ for you every time you hit ", just like it auto fills in the ending quote for you or an ending bracket (which can be annoying sometimes). But it would be a IDE thing, not a compiler thing.

Comment: No, there is no way to do that. Such feature would prevent you from defining string constants, which cannot be constructed using interpolated strings.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight If he really wanted to could he switch the compilation, so that consts need to be declared as $ and interpolated strings not?

Comment: Having an implicit `$` would be a bad idea.  What do you expect will happen when you leave your job and someone replaces you?  That person will reasonably but incorrectly expect those strings to *not* be interpolated.  Bad idea.

Comment: There's nothing preventing you from creating a VS extension that does what @Quantic describes. At least that way you'd end up with valid code and avoid the situation Amy described.

Comment: Resharper suggests changing a string to string interpolation.  Just press Alt + Enter when constructing a string.