# HotKey or Auto-Expansion for Interpolated Strings in VS

Tags: c#, autocomplete, autohotkey

I want to save myself a few keystrokes when typing C# interpolated strings in VS 2015/2017.

From what I can see, there isn't any built in functionality for this.

Somewhat related question here: [Automatic interpolated strings](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44166762/3546415)

I'm settling on an AHK script for now that makes `ctrl+[` a hotkey for this in VS. I'm wondering if anyone knows of a better way?

```
#SingleInstance force
#IfWinActive, ahk_exe devenv.exe
^[::
SendInput,$"
```

I also considered the script below to directly expand the typing of `$`, but this would hinder the typing of `$` on its own.

```
#SingleInstance force
#IfWinActive, ahk_exe devenv.exe
:*:$::$"
```

Comment: What keystrokes are you trying to replace. Interpolated strings are just prefixed with $, aren't they? Are you just trying to make a hotkey for typing a $?

Comment: @TylerLee Well a hotkey to type both `$"` and the IDE expands the `"` with an ending quote and places the cursor in between. Still, not much to it, but strings are so common it'd be nice to save a few strokes and I'm trying to make it super simple to kick the habit of starting strings with only `"` and then needing to use `+` as an after thought.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the IDE behavior directly to the script

```
#SingleInstance force
#IfWinActive, ahk_exe devenv.exe
^[::
SendInput,$""{Left}
```

*If this doesn't answer your question please add more information for non VS users about what you are trying to achieve*