# Visual studio 2015 C# Shorten command

Tags: c#, visual-studio

How can I make a text/command to shorten a command like: `Console.Write("");` so that if I just write `cw` then it would automatically write `Console.Write("");`?

Comment: [Creating a Code Snippet](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165394.aspx)

Comment: @GiladGreen `cw` is for `Console.WriteLine()` and not `Console.Write()` :) That said, I don't know if you can override Visual Studio default snippets.

Comment: Thanks :D I thought i have to create them.

Comment: Here's the standard list - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z41h7fat.aspx - it might be of some use too

Comment: I'm not sure why this question is being down-voted. Despite the obvious answer to the specific case in the OP, the general question is relevant. Maybe rephrase this question to ask about Code Snippets and their alternatives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the comments, `cw` is actually a preset code snippet for `Console.WriteLine()` that can be expanded by pressing Tab. You can also create [custom code snippets](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165394(v=vs.100).aspx).

But you do specifically ask about expanding `cw` on its own without pressing Tab as needed for Code Snippets. I was actually just recently looking to do [something similar for interpolated strings](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46477608/3546415) and haven't come across anything within VS.

If you want to automatically expand `cw` as code or want to customize hotkeys, I've found simple [AutoHotKey (AHK)](https://autohotkey.com/) scripts like the ones below to be useful for that. You can can do a lot more with AHK as well, like keep key presses in memory. It can really lend flexible scripting like customization to your IDE. Notice the `#IfWinActive, ahk_exe devenv.exe` line makes the script specific to VS.

**Make `cw` an AutoExpanding HotString (Tab not required)**

```
#SingleInstance force
#IfWinActive, ahk_exe devenv.exe
:*:cw::Console.WriteLine(
```

**Make `cw` a Tab expanded HotString (like VS code snippets)**

```
#SingleInstance force
#IfWinActive, ahk_exe devenv.exe
#Hotstring EndChars `t
::cw::Console.WriteLine(
```

**Hotkey for Ctrl+[**

```
#SingleInstance force
#IfWinActive, ahk_exe devenv.exe
^[::
SendInput,Console.WriteLine(
```